# Why does MySQL not use my index in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

create table statement:

```
create table stock_master.turnover_rate_trade
(
    id int auto_increment
        constraint `PRIMARY`
            primary key,
    before_day int null,
    pre_day int null,
    turnover_rate double null ,
    max_rise double null ,
    keep_day int null ,
    code varchar(50) null ,
    date date null ,
    real_keep int null ,
    rate double null ,
    create_time timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP null,
    update_time timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP null,
    constraint uindex
        unique (before_day, pre_day, turnover_rate, max_rise, keep_day, code, date)
);
```

my select statement:

```
select id,
       before_day,
       pre_day,
       turnover_rate,
       max_rise,
       keep_day,
       code,
       date
       real_keep,
       rate,
       create_time,
       update_time
from turnover_rate_trade
where
   before_day=6 and pre_day =3 and turnover_rate=22.1 and max_rise =7.1 and keep_day=5 and 
   code='100000' and date='2022-02-02'
```

Execute the plan:
[image]

I am not a professional dba, avoid indexes invalidation as much as possible.
It is clearly written in the conditions, but doesn't work.

The table data information:

```
rows: 2 hundred million
before_day: 5~29
pre_day: 0~4
keep_day: 0~29
turnover_rate: 1~23
max_rise: 1~29
```

evenly distributed

as suggested:
It took me over an hour to delete and rebuild index.

```
create index turnover
                on turnover_rate_trade (before_day, pre_day, turnover_rate, max_rise, keep_day, code, date)
```

Now it works!Can someone explain?
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "index fail"?

Comment: @Bohemian The `EXPLAIN` output says it's not using the index.

Comment: I can't imagine why you would "avoid indexes as much as possible." Indexes make databases work well. If they're unfamiliar, I suggest https://use-the-index-luke.com as an introduction.

Comment: How many rows are in the table? How many different values are in each column of the indexed columns?

Comment: Have you tried the most selective column first in the index? I don't know MySql well, but it might be calculating the cost of using the index based on the first few columns/bytes, and it may decide that 200M/(29-5+1) index related reads, followed by the data-row reads may be costlier than just reading all data-rows. Try placing the date first, if it is the column with most unique values.

Comment: The range of values in each column is interesting, but not as important as how _frequent_ the values are in those columns. MySQL's optimizer skips using an index if it calculates that the values you are searching for will match a large enough subset of the table. Sort of like the reason common words like "the" are not included in the index at the back of a book.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...,` - This may give some more clues.

Comment: The "cardinality" is relevant for the entire index, not for each column.  Please provide the MySQL version number.

Comment: And if the JSON is not sufficient, I will ask for an "Optimizer Trace".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` are approximate values, stored in binary.  `22.1` is a decimal value that cannot be stored exactly in any `DOUBLE`.  It is risky to test with `=` with a `DOUBLE` on one side and a non-integral decimal number on the other side.

I understand that this fails to explain why the Index was (according to the `EXPLAIN`) not used.  But let's fix the comparison first.

Plan A:  Use some form of range test.  (This will definitely mess up using the index.)

Plan B: switch the column to `DECIMAL`.  (Such an `ALTER` will take a long time.)

You possibly have a typo here:

```
   code,
   date        -- perhaps you wanted a comma?
   real_keep,
```

Another issue...  You have not specified a `PRIMARY KEY` (and that `UNIQUE` key cannot be promoted to PK due to nullability of most of its columns).  A PK is really needed for all tables.

Suggest making columns `NOT NULL` where appropriate.

Suggest adding an explicit PK.

(Again, I can't explain the failure to your your index.)